# custom battery for CO2 generation

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

I want to design a small, cheap device that generates CO2 but I also want to capture the voltage to drive an LED. Any advice about which half-cell reaction I should use (oxalate?) or battery design. I do not want any CO to be produced.Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Plant a lemon tree - this will cover CO2 generation. You will also get some oxygen, shade, and other useful stuff. Don't ever burn any part of the tree or you may get CO.

AS far as LED goes, wait till lemons are ripe and make yourself a [Lemon Battery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_battery). You will need zink and copper metals for the electrodes, a US penny will provide both inexpensively.